# Rails paperclip and SVG images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, paperclip

model.rb:

`has_attached_file :image
validates_attachment :image,
  :content_type => { :content_type => ['image/svg+xml'] }`


Results in: "Image has an extension that does not match its contents, is invalid, and is invalid"

When trying to attach an SVG file that is in fact valid.

Note, I've also tried the `'image/svg-xml'` type with the same result

Comment: Can you try `file --mime <file>` and `mimetype <file>` at the command line to see what type is found.  What OS are you using?

Comment: How do I do this on Windows 7?

Comment: In the rails console, `Paperclip.run("file", "-b --mime :file", :file => '<file>')` where <file> is your SVG file.

Comment: ````Cocaine::CommandNotFoundError````

Comment: The problem is coming from the spoofing detection which was put into Paperclip at version 4.  Basically it wants to compare the output from the `file` command against `MIME::Types`.  Seems Windows doesn't have a `file` command, so Paperclip will set it to `""` which obviously doesn't match.  You can disable spoofing by following the solution in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527092/paperclip-is-not-supporting-doc-file/22529404#22529404

Comment: This is good information.

Answer (score 5):

The solution to this problem for me was to make sure that the contents of the SVG file start with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
```

Under the hood, Paperclip uses the `file` command to make sure that the contents of the file match the name of the file. That check seems to want this declaration at the beginning of SVG files.

I find this to be unfortunate considering that a [sample file from W3C](https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/alphachannel.svg) doesn't even have it in there:

```
<svg id='svg1' viewBox='0 0 100 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
  <circle r="32" cx="35" cy="65" fill="#F00" opacity="0.5"/>
  <circle r="32" cx="65" cy="65" fill="#0F0" opacity="0.5"/>
  <circle r="32" cx="50" cy="35" fill="#00F" opacity="0.5"/>
</svg>
```

I'm considering adding some logic in the model to add this to the beginning of the contents if it's not already there before it runs the check. Not sure if I should really do that though.

Answer (score 2):

As Chris Peters mentioned, under the hood the `file` command is being used to check the mime type. On my Ubuntu machine, PaperClip (at the application level) correctly identifies the mime type as `'image/svg+xml'`, but the system command `file` identifies the mime type as `text/html`. (You can test this by running `file --mime-type your_file.svg`).

One solution to this is to define a content-type mapping the accepts svgs with either `image/svg+xml` or `text/html`:

```
Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = {
  svg: %w(image/svg+xml text/html)
}
```

This can be done in a PaperClip initializer, for example `config/initializers/paperclip.rb` in a Rails app.

Personally I feel like this is acceptable if you're taking user input from say an admin in a cms, because you can probably trust that they're not trying to get up to mischief. I'm not sure how safe this would be otherwise though.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer has resolved my issue but I had to change *text/html* by **text/plain**  .
Here's my config for mime-types:

```
    Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = {
      :json => 'text/plain',
      :twbx => 'application/zip',
      :twb => 'application/xml',
      svg: %w(image/svg+xml text/plain)
    }
```